# Rediect to $1 passing params and using pretty urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

after a lot Google/Youtube/Stackoverflow research and putting random things together I finally got something that partly works here:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SimpleMVCTest/


#Make sure it's not an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Make sure its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#Rewrite the request to REQUESTED_FILENAME
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?get=$1 [L]
```

There is two issues I have noticed with this

1: Giving `www.example.com/car/1` will result in 500 Internal Error but if i write `www.example.com/car` it works fine. How do i make it so i can go car/1 and it will not give 500 internal Error

2: if i write `www.example.com/somethingthatdoesnotexist` or `www.example.com/somethingthatdoesnotexist/1` it gives 500 internal but should just redirect to 404 but its not found

How would i do this?

Comment: You forgot to tell how `www.example.com/car/1` should be rewritten for your php file? Will it be `car.php?id=1` or something like that?

Comment: That's not complete answer. Will it be `car.php?id=1`. So `/foo/123` will be become `foo.php?id=123`?

Comment: First decide, what do you want, Redirect Or rewrite?  Rewrite doesn’t change URL in browser address bar

Comment: @Samir I what to rewrite so if i type `www.example.com/example/1` which would be same as `www.example.com/example=1` so above code in question works for www.example.com/index but when i pass `www.example.com/index/1` it give 500 internal its something do with this i think `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?get=$1 [L]` because i am using `get=$1` but i am also using it for the file as `$1.php`

Comment: @Ash  since first part your file name, you can try it `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?get=$2`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very good approach, you should not rewrite everything to a file like `$1.php` as you will be trying to request files like `car/1.php` which is not what you want: This will lead to the internal server error because on the next rewrite it will try to get `car/1.php.php`, then `car/1.php.php.php` etc. etc.

Instead you should rewrite everything to a fixed file like `index.php` and handle the logic in php. You can get the requested url (you could even add it as a query variable), parse it and include or redirect to any file you want.